# Isolated indices using Python

Tags: python, numpy

The following code identifies isolated indices based on the condition that there has to be at least two adjacent neighbors. To be a neighbor, `(i,j)` should have at least two of the following indices: `(i+1,j),(i-1,j),(i,j+1),(i,j-1)`. However, I would  like to add another condition which excludes index `(0,0)` and excludes the specific index if that's the only one on the last row. I have two examples.

(1) If I have `indices =  [(0, 0),(0,1),(1,0),(2,0)]`, the isolated index should only be `(0,1)`.

(2) If I have `indices =  [(0, 0),(1,0),(2,0)]`, the isolated index should be none.

```
import numpy as np
indices =  [(0, 0),(0,1),(1,0),(2,0)]
def get_isolated_indices(indices):
    indices = np.array(indices)
    indices = indices[np.argsort(indices[:, 0])]
    
    # I'm calling the 1st number in each pair the row number
    # and the 2nd number in each pair the column number.

    # max_row_num = max_vals[0]
    # max_col_num = max_vals[1]
    max_vals = np.max(indices, axis=0)

    # For easier indexing
    rows = indices[:, 0]
    cols = indices[:, 1]
    
    isolated = []
    
    for i in range(len(indices)):
        this_row = indices[i, 0]
        this_col = indices[i, 1]
        
        # If this_row = 0 or this_row = max_row_val (in this case, 2), nearby rows are not allowed to have values -1 or 3.
        nearby_row_vals = list(range(max(0, this_row - 1), min(this_row + 1, max_vals[0]) + 1))
        nearby_col_vals = list(range(max(0, this_col - 1), min(this_col + 1, max_vals[1]) + 1))
        
        # These masks get the index pairs with the same row number or same column number.
        same_row_mask = rows == this_row
        same_col_mask = cols == this_col
        
        # These masks get the index pairs who have an allows row or column number
        # that is different from the current index pair's row/column number.
        diff_rows_mask = (rows >= np.min(nearby_row_vals)) & (rows <= np.max(nearby_row_vals)) & (rows != this_row)
        diff_cols_mask = (cols >= np.min(nearby_col_vals)) & (cols <= np.max(nearby_col_vals)) & (cols != this_col)
        
        # Need to make sure we avoid including neighbors that are different in both row and column number.
        # E.g. we don't want to count (1,1) as a neighbor of (0,0)
        intersection1 = np.logical_and(same_row_mask, same_col_mask)
        intersection2 = np.logical_and(same_row_mask, diff_cols_mask)
        intersection3 = np.logical_and(diff_rows_mask, same_col_mask)
        
        # final_intersection is a 1D array with length = len(indices)/
        # final_intersection is True if the index pair is a neighbor (or is the index pair itself)
        final_intersection = np.logical_or(np.logical_or(intersection1, intersection2), intersection3)

        # Need to subtract by 1 because the index pair is initially counted as its own neighbor.
        num_neighbors = np.sum(final_intersection) - 1
        
        if num_neighbors <= 1:
            isolated.append((this_row, this_col))
            
    return isolated

A = get_isolated_indices(indices)
print("A =",A)
```

Comment: What is the logic to be _neighbor_? Is point P a neighbor of (x, y) if P is in (x +/- 1, y +/-1)?

Comment: To be a neighbor, ```(i,j)``` should have at least two of the following indices:  ```(i+1,j),(i-1,j),(i,j+1),(i,j-1)```.